# Error when migrating from catkin_make to catkin build

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, catkin-tools

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a problem when switching from catkin_make to catkin build. Although I have already refered to the migration guide (https://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migration.html) but I still could not figure out what is the culprit. As for the `Altimeter.h` which is complained to have been missing, It is there in `./devel_cb/include/cvg_sim_msgs` directory. The error is as below:

```
Errors     << cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins:make /home/alfa/catkin_ws/logs_cb/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/build.make.000.log                                                                                             In file included from /home/alfa/catkin_ws/src/tum_simulator/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_baro.cpp:29:0/home/alfa/catkin_ws/src/tum_simulator/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/include/hector_quadrotor_gazebo_plugin    /gazebo_ros_baro.h:41:36: fatal error: cvg_sim_msgs/Altimeter.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/hector_gazebo_ros_baro.dir/src/gazebo_ros_baro.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/hector_gazebo_ros_baro.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [all] Error 2

cd /home/alfa/catkin_ws/build_cb/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins; catkin build --get-env cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins | catkin env -si  /usr/bin/make --jobserver-fds=6,7 -j; cd -

Failed     << cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins:make           [ Exited with code 2 ]                                                                                                                                 
Failed    <<< cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins                [ 13.8 seconds ]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/356995/error-when-migrating-from-catkin_make-to-catkin-build/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2020-07-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2020-07-13**:
It would help to see `package.xml` and `CMakeLists.txt` for the `cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins` package. My initial guess is that a dependency on `cfg_sim_msgs` is not being configured correctly for the build system.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2020-07-13**:
@Thomas D: Thank you very much for the hint. By your hint, I've finally managed to build it successfully by altering the dependency in the cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins in that to include cvg_sim_msgs both in both places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The issue was finally resolved by altering the dependency of `cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins` package to include `cvg_sim_msgs` both in `package.xml` and `CMakeLists.txt`. Kudos to @Thomas D for giving the great hint.

---

Originally posted by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) with karma: 1053 on 2020-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0